# Check if array of objects contains all the values of an array of integers

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to know if all the values of an array of integers are in an array of objects?
If the values of the array of integers are all in the array of objects, as return I intend true and false the opposite, that is, the values are not all present in the object.

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-p2a5kq)

```
 Sizes = [
    {
      id: 1,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
    },
    {
      id: 4,
    },
  ];

  Number = [1, 2, 3];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `every` + `some`:

```
Number.every(n => Sizes.some(obj => obj.id === n))
```

```js
 Sizes = [
    {
      id: 1,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
    },
    {
      id: 4,
    },
  ];

  Number = [1, 2, 3];
  
console.log(Number.every(n => Sizes.some(obj => obj.id === n)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `map` the values to a new array of values to check, then check if the values `includes` the numbers.

```js
const sizes = [{
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
  },
];

const check = (ns, szs) => {
  const nsToCheck = szs.map((x) => x.id); // get values
  for (const number of ns) {
    if (!nsToCheck.includes(number)) return false; // return false if !include
  }
  return true; // otherwise return true
}

const numbersWillSucceed = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const numbersWillFail = [1, 5];

console.log("Will succeed: ",check(numbersWillSucceed, sizes));
console.log("Will fail: ",check(numbersWillFail, sizes));
```

Comment: it would be better to make `nsToCheck` a `Set`

Answer (score 1):

You can easily solve this problem with functions already existing for JavaScript and Arrays.

With:

```
const test1 = [
    {
      id: 1,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
    },
    {
      id: 4,
    },
];
```

and:

```
const test2 = [1, 2, 3];
```

One can use:

```
test2.every(t2 => test1.find(t1 => t1.id === t2) !== undefined)
```

to check if every element from `test2` exists in `test1`.
It simply tests (`every`) whether every element from `test1` is contained in the array `test2` (with `find`).

Please do not use variables like "Number", since Number already exists in JavasScript, see also https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow#builtinglobals

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify` to compare them.

```
const ids = this.sizes.map(item => item.id);

const result = JSON.stringify(ids)==JSON.stringify(this.Number);

console.log(result);
```

You can check the demo here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7c4id8

**Update:** To make sure the order of them are same before compare, I will compare the sorted items.

```
const result = JSON.stringify(ids.sort())==JSON.stringify(this.Number.sort());
```